selection_interval gets stuck
I'm trying to create an interactive figure using interval_selection as shown in the example here. I can get the figures to load properly, but for some reason the value on x-axis at index 0 is getting stuck on the last value of the x-axis found on the small graph and then corrects itself whenever that  last value ends up in the view.
altair==4.2.0
Examples
See photos for examples:
Selection at start of graph
Selection at middle of graph
Selection at end of graph
In these examples, you'll see that the fov is 792 at run_idx 3 for all selections except for when fov 792 (based on the x-axis) actually in the selection.
Code
def plot_align_err_heatmap(df, channel_choice, orientation) -> alt.Chart:
    """Generate a heatmap for alignment errors based on the selected channel and orientation.
    
    
    
    Parameters:
    - df (pd.DataFrame): The DataFrame containing the alignment error data.
    - channel_choice (str): The selected channel (e.g., 'AF405', 'AF458').
    - orientation (str): The selected orientation ('horz' or 'vert').

    Returns:
    - alt.Chart: The Altair chart object representing the heatmap.
    """
    alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()

    to_view = f"px_err_{channel_choice}_{orientation}:Q"

    interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=["x"])
    focus_tool_tips = [
        alt.Tooltip(
            f"px_err_{channel_choice}_vert:N",
            title="Vertical Pixel Error:",
            format=".2f",
        ),
        alt.Tooltip(
            f"px_err_{channel_choice}_horz:N",
            title="Horizontal Pixel Error:",
            format=".2f",
        ),
        alt.Tooltip("fov:N", title="FOV:"),
        alt.Tooltip("run_idx:N", title="Run Index:"),
    ]
    title = f"Channel {channel_choice}: {orientation}"
    base_chart = (
        alt.Chart(df, title=title)
        .mark_rect()
        .encode(
            x="fov:O",
            y="run_idx:O",
            color=alt.Color(
                to_view,
                title="Pixel Error",
                scale=alt.Scale(scheme="redblue", domain=[-3, 3]),
            ),
        )
    )

    top_chart = base_chart.encode(
        x=alt.X("fov:O", scale=alt.Scale(domain=interval.ref())),
        tooltip=focus_tool_tips,
    ).properties(width=800, height=300)

    bottom_chart = (
        base_chart.encode(x=alt.X("fov:O", axis=None))
        .add_selection(interval)
        .properties(
            width=800,
            height=50
        )
    )

    combined_heatmap = top_chart & bottom_chart
    return combined_heatmap

I've tried changing the data types to categorical, and quantitative.
